# Sorting the collection with date and time in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the below usecase. I need expert advice to resolve my problem.

1. Following is the structure of my document
   {_id, name, create_dtm, deviceName,poolName, eventType, location, message
   }
2. I have 100 collections in my db. Out 100 there are 30 records with the same date and time (no millisecond/microsecond difference also).
3. I have written pagination by sorting the collection by created_dtm and setting the Limit() and skip().
4. On the first page, I am 1 - 25 records properly with few records from 30 records. (1-20 some other records and 5 records from 30 records).
5. On the second page, few records from 5 records are again showing up which are already listed on the first page.

As per my very little knowledge of Mongo, I am thinking sorting with the only created_dtm is not sufficient. Please advise what will the best way to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Praveen if the answer worked please approve so that we can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDB, `_id` (ObjectID) is the unique identifier, also it stores the timestamp when the document was created. So you can use the `_id` to sort the documents and you will not get the same documents again.

For more, please have look at the official documentation of `_id` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field).

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks Vijay, this really helped. I have one more query. If I sort the timestamp(ts) and _id then I have to write a compound index with ts and _id to resolve the performance issue. But currently, I have an individual index defined on _id, ts. Is it a good idea to have a compound index with these variables.

Comment: Yes, you can use the compound index, in fact, compound index is only way to optimize the complex queries.
you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57595803/mongodb-aggregate-pipeline-slow-after-first-match-step/57713897#57713897 for optimization