# mongodb (pymongo) aggregate is slow even after filtering with $match

Tags: mongodb, search, aggregation-framework, pymongo, dot-product

**tl;dr**: I have 4 million documents in a collection, I filter down to 6000 with `$match` and then perform an operation with `$project`. The `$project` takes 60 seconds! If I run the same `$project` operation on a mock database containing only 6000 documents, it takes 0.5 seconds. Why this mismatch and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**: It is not the `$project` step that takes 60 seconds, but any step i place after it. For instance another `$match` that filters the output of `$project` to get dot products higher than X.

I am using pymongo library for Python and I have MongoDb version v4.4.3 installed on Windows.
I have 4 million documents in a collection. Each document is like this:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("...")
document_id: 0,
vector: Array
hash_value: 123
}
```

where `vector` is an array with 300 doubles ranging from -1 to 1. I have an index on `hash_value`.

Given an input array also with 300 elements in the range (-1,1), I want to calculate the dot product between the input array and each array in the collection that have a given `hash_value`.
I use an aggregation pipeline *(see at the end of the question for the full pipeline)* that does:

- `$match`: filter to get only documents that match the desired `hash_value`
- `$project`: apply the dot product to the elements returned by `$match`.
- `$match`: filter only dot products output by `$project` that are higher than X.

The `$match` step filters down from 4 million to just about 6000 documents, The `$project` step is very fast, but any step I include after (e.g. the second ``` $match`` **takes 1 minute** to run! Even if I just return the results from ``` $project``` and iterate over them in Python it takes 1 minute.

To test, I also created a mock database with only 6000 documents and a single `hash_value`. If I run the same exact `$match`,`$project`,`$match` pipeline on this 6000-document mock database (here `$match` passes all 6000 documents to the next step because they all match the input`hash_value`), it **takes only 0.5 seconds**!

It seems that I can calculate a fast dot product by filtering down to an acceptable size, but then **I can't use the results in any way** because they are too slow to load.

My questions are:

1. why does this happen? (I'd like, if possible, an explanation on what's happening under the hood)
2. is there any way to prevent this?
3. Would splitting documents in different collections help?
4. If you think there's no way to achieve good performance with MongoDB, do you know any other database where I could do this kind of operation fast with millions of documents?
5. Am I structuring my data wrong? Is there a better way to structure my data for the purpose of calculating the dot product between query and documents?

Below is the pipeline:

```
{
    "$match": {"$expr": {"$in": ["$hash_value", [123]]}}
},
{"$project": {
    "_id":0,
    "document_id": 1,
    "dotProduct": {
        "$let": {"vars": {"queryVector": [0.2,-0.12,-0.9,....,0.14,0.56]}, "in":{
        "$reduce": {
            "input": { "$range": [ 0, { "$size": "$vector" }] },
            "initialValue": 0,
            "in": { "$add": [ "$$value", { "$multiply": [ { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$vector", "$$this" ] }, { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$queryVector", "$$this" ] } ] } ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
    }
},
{   
    "$match":{"dotProduct":{"$gt":0.5}}
}
```

Notes:

1. I use `$in` because actually there could be more than one input `hash_value`
2. I have verified that the first `$match` step is actually filtering out correctly
3. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57595803/mongodb-aggregate-pipeline-slow-after-first-match-step) question already. I followed some of the tips in the answer (using allowDiskUse = True, indexing the field I am using for the `$match` step), but none of the other comments seem relevant to my case.
4. If I just keep the first `$match`, get the results and iterate over them in Python it also takes about 1 minute.

Here is the profiler log:

```
                "allowDiskUse" : true,
                "cursor" : {

                },
                "$readPreference" : {
                        "mode" : "secondaryPreferred"
                },
                "$db" : "similarity"
        },
        "keysExamined" : 0,
        "docsExamined" : 4000000,
        "cursorExhausted" : true,
        "numYield" : 4789,
        "nreturned" : 1,
        "queryHash" : "9A0FCEC0",
        "planCacheKey" : "9A0FCEC0",
        "locks" : {
                "ReplicationStateTransition" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "w" : NumberLong(4792)
                        }
                },
                "Global" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(4792)
                        }
                },
                "Database" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(4791)
                        }
                },
                "Collection" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(4791)
                        }
                },
                "Mutex" : {
                        "acquireCount" : {
                                "r" : NumberLong(2)
                        }
                }
        },
        "flowControl" : {

        },
        "storage" : {
                "data" : {
                        "bytesRead" : NumberLong("15295638272"),
                        "timeReadingMicros" : NumberLong(57621295)
                }
        },
        "responseLength" : 176,
        "protocol" : "op_query",
        "millis" : 63990,
        "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
        "ts" : ISODate("2021-03-26T10:06:56.185Z"),
        ...
}
```

Thank you in advance for your generous help.

Comment: Is there an index on the `hash_value` field?

Comment: @Joe yes there is and it is the only index in the collection

Comment: How big are the queryVector and Vector arrays?

Comment: @Joe please check my updates to the question, I realized that the $project step is very fast, and it's what follows that is slow (another $match, or just iterating over the results in python). In answer to your question, queryVector and Vector are a list of 300 elements

Comment: how are you timing that?

Comment: I run the pipeline a) with only the first step, b) with first and second step, c) with all steps. a) and b) are very fast, c) takes one minute. In case b), using python, i do results = collection.aggregate(pipeline) and it's very fast. However, if I iterate over the results cursor to actually use the results, it's super slow (e.g. ids = [i["document_id"] for i in results if i["dotProduct"] > 0.5] takes 1 minute)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230401/discussion-between-joe-and-liflif).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
the first `$match` step used `$in` which is more expensive than `$eq`. Using `$eq` reduces response time to 1.5 - 2.5 seconds. The reason I couldn't figure it out is that lazy execution caused to make it "seem" like `$match` was fast. In other words, `$match` > `$project` seemed to run fast until I tried to take the results from the cursor. MongoDB actually doesn't run the pipeline until you get the results from the cursor, and this is why it is hard to pin-point the step of the pipeline that takes the longest.

The new pipeline becomes

```
{
    "$match": { "hash_value" : 123 }
},
{"$project": {
    "_id":0,
    "document_id": 1,
    "dotProduct": {
        "$let": {"vars": {"queryVector": [0.2,-0.12,-0.9,....,0.14,0.56]}, "in":{
        "$reduce": {
            "input": { "$range": [ 0, { "$size": "$vector" }] },
            "initialValue": 0,
            "in": { "$add": [ "$$value", { "$multiply": [ { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$vector", "$$this" ] }, { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$queryVector", "$$this" ] } ] } ] }
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
    }
},
{   
    "$match":{"dotProduct":{"$gt":0.5}}
}
```